# Prolog instantiate and assign a variable even when predicate fails

Tags: prolog

The essential question: how can I assign to an instance variable when a predicate fails?

I have two predicate "functions" (probably wrong terminology). The first predicate calls the second predicate with a new instantiation variable (unassigned). I assign a value to the new variable in the second predicate. However, the second predicate fails. The way I am implementing it, since the predicate fails, the new variable is still unassigned after returning to the first predicate.

```
func(X, Y) :-
  func2(X, NewX);
  write(NewX).

func2(X, NewX) :-
  NewX is X+1, false.
```

This prints:

```
| ?- func(1,1).
_283
```

However, if the second predicate returns true like so,

```
func(X, Y) :-
  func2(X, NewX),
  write(NewX).

func2(X, NewX) :-
  NewX is X+1.
```

Then it prints:

```
| ?- func(1,1).
2

yes
```

How can I assign an instance when a predicate fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Prolog, when a predicate call *fails*, all variable bindings that were created after the call are **undone** on backtracking. Consequently, there is no way to "fail *and* unify" in pure Prolog.

---

To solve your issue in pure Prolog, declaratively describe the cases that **hold**.

For example, in your case, you obviously have **2 possible cases**:

- **either** `NewX` is *equal* to  `X + 1`
- **or** it *isn't*.

So, in Prolog, this could read:

```
integer_successor(X0, X, true)  :- X #= X0 + 1.
integer_successor(X0, X, false) :- X #\= X0 + 1.
```

Given these definitions, you can now use:

```
integer_successor(X, NewX, Truth)
```

and then use `Truth` to distinguish the cases.

For example:

```
other_pred(true)  :- ...
other_pred(false) :- ...
```

This lets you describe the different cases by **pattern matching**, and *retains* [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) and generality of your code: You can use this as a true relation, in all directions, including for the most general query where all arguments are free variables.